# IDEA android project using new image asset, doesn't update all ic_launcher.png files?

Tags: android, android-studio

Been coding in Java for years, but new to Android development. Purchased a commonsware subscription https://commonsware.com/warescription and for android questions on their android book they mention to ask in Stackoverflow, so here I am...

I have Android support in IDEA enabled (since I use IDEA as my standard java IDE, I didn't install the standalone Android Studio, but it should behave the same from what I gather.) Using IDEA 15, I click on my android project src > new image asset, and I add this image (as the book suggests based on the step I'm on) https://commonsware.com/misc/molecule.png

However, I noticed it only changed the  mipmap-hdpi ic_launcher.png files.  I'm using Genymotion plugin (since I couldn't get any emulator to work within the IDE, but that's another topic), and I have Genymotion set with a Galaxy S4 4.2.2 configuration which works just fine, but it must be using the drawable-hdpi asset since I don't see the new image modified by the "new image asset" process, so my questions are:

1) How come none of the drawable-xzy were modified? Only the mipmap-hdpi ones were modified?

2) How so you know which file will be used by the device? or in this case the device I configured in Genymotion?  How come it chose one of the drawable-xyz assets?

Thanks, Rick

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my AndroidManifest wa using android:icon="@drawable
when it needed to be @mipmap.

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Not

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```